# Uncaught TypeError: Reflux.listenTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

My code looks like this:

```
mixins: [Reflux.listenTo(ItemStore,"onChange")],

....

onChange: function(items) {
    this.setState({items: items});
},
```

when I run npm start and on browser when I look into console, the error refers to the "mixins" line. If I change  the string within quotation "onChange", I still get the same error.

Comment: have you required `reflux` and installed reflux library?

Comment: Yes I have. I had forgotten to install reflux, but this error I got after installing, and I have required reflux.

Comment: My bad, after reviewing several times, turns out that I had done mistake in "require" part. Resolved.